# What tables I need to create in order to keep a simple structure?

Tags: sql

I'm not that good in SQL, please advice guys, what tables I need to have and how to make selections. I have an `recordId` which may have several `headers` which may have several `fields`. All of those are just `String`s. By selecting a `recordId` I need to fetch associated `headers` and their `fields`.

Comment: Can a field have more than one header? Can a header have more than one record? If the answer to both these is no then Yossi's solution will suffice. If you answer yes to either then you'll need the many-to-many style solution that FSou1 has shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tbl_record
recordId

tbl_headers
headerId

tbl_fields
fieldId

tbl_record_to_headers
id
recordId
headerId

tbl_header_to_fields
id
headerId
fieldId
```

Isn't it?

Comment: There are separate tables, and no need to make relationship in data tables- you have for that many-to-many tables `tbl_record_to_headers` & `tbl_header_to_fields`

Comment: Why do you think so? You will leave `many-to-many` just because need to add 2 separate tables? And what will you do, when PM comes and tell you to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need 3 tables.

Records: record_id

Headers: header_id, record_id, header_val

Fields: field_id, Header_id, field_val

Comment: You will have big-big data table with relationship columns, by the way without `many-to-many` option, which could be need in future- pretty hardcore